# Why ms word table cell text jumps to next line?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am writing a table in ms word 2016, I want to adjust a table to make for example 2 words in the same cell, but when I write the second word it goes to the next line, see image below:
[image]

there is a huge space in front of the first word but the scond word goes down, please tell me how to solve that, the table have a lot of columns and I have a little space, and the text should be in font size 14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a few things to check:  First, ensure you are displaying the top level ruler (in the View tab, ensure "Ruler" is checked in the Show group).  Refer to the image below.

!Word menu display ruler checkbox(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Aryt.jpg)

Next, with the top ruler displayed, verify that the right margin is not offset to the left.  Go to Home tab, Paragraph group, then expand the paragraph settings menu.  You can also type "Paragraph Settings" in the Tell Me box.  Verify that the right paragraph is set at "0."  Select the whole table and apply this so that the correct formatting is set for the whole table.

If the step above doesn't fix it, also go to "Table Properties" (type "Table Properties" in Tell Me box).  Under the Table tab, go to "Options."  In Options, you can set the left and right margins for the entire table.  The default (assuming you've set the display as inches) is 0.08" but you can change it to something more or less.

Comment: thank you dear MAK, but this does not solve my problem.

Comment: @honar.cs, can you post a screenshot of your table with the ruler displayed?  Did you check the cell margins in the table properties?  Thanks

Comment: by changing the rule, my problem is solved, thank you.

Comment: Hello, if this solved your problem, can you upvote the answer?

Comment: Posted a Screenshot explaining this answer from MAK - it helped.  Note the ruler will not show the paragrah"thumb sliders" when this extreme scenario happens - that is your visual clue that this table cell will force a single letter or character per line. (Thanks MAK)

Answer (score 1):

MAK's Answer is the trick to fixing this.  The Ruler being visible helps once you see it fixed - it will then be obvious to you in the future.  The trick is to get your cursor into the actual paragrpah text in the cell you care about and then to bring up the paragraph properties for that specific text block.   TL;DNR - The right paragraph is so large that it is forcing the text to the left.
[image]